# GDB console can't show the result of printf

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, printf

I'm using gdb in RedHat to debug C++ code. To better debug my code, I added `printf("XXX")`.

However, after the execution of `printf("XXX")`, the gdb console didn't show XXX.

Other parts of my code works fine.

Comment: If you execute the program without debugger do you see the XXX on the console?

Comment: It seems to be no.@Hayt

Comment: Seams to be a buffer issue with GDB: it's append also to me, that at the end of debug, remaining data from stdout buffer isn't flush. Try `printf("XXX\n");`

Comment: so maybe the binary you are debugging is still the old one.

Comment: You are right, thank you.Why not write a more detailed answer?@Garf365

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's likely that your output is line-buffered, and because you didn't end the print with a newline, the output hasn't been flushed.  Three easy fixes:

1. `std::printf("XXX"); std::fflush(stdout);`
2. `std::printf("XXX\n");`
3. `std::puts("XXX");`

Also, take care if you're mixing C-style `FILE*` i/o with C++-style streams.

Comment: I am curious about why this isn't the same case for Windows? I mean, under Windows, debug with Visual Studio, I get output every time with `cout << "hello";`, no extra `std::endl` or `std::flush` needed. Is it because Visual Studio already taking care of this?

Comment: @Rick, probably the library there is using a different buffering strategy.  It's not a platform I've had any contact with, so that would be pure speculation on my part.  Perhaps worth asking a question, if it's not already addressed by one?

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I don't wanna bother others by asking this question,after all, it's kinda a useless question. I just feel a bit surprised when I don't find any GDB tutorial mentioning this. I mean, this is very important when debugging. For exmaple, I come from Windows, have no idea what's wrong when I don't see the `cout` output at first time.